# PouchDB get on _id returns nor date neither error

Tags: ionic2, pouchdb

In a PouchDB database, I have some docs:

```
{
    _id: '765541',
    title: 'Mickey Mouse'
},
{
    _id: '78910',
    title: 'Donald Duck'
}
```

I'm trying to run the `get()` method like this:

```
localCharacter(id: string){
    let db = this._db;
    let character: any;
    console.log('Look for : ' + id + ' in local db');

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      db.get(id).then((result) => {
        console.log('Character: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
        character= result.row; 
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Some errors : ' + error);
        character = false;
      });
      console.log('Resolve : ' + character);
      resolve(character);
    })
  }
```

but following message keeps popping up in the console:

```
Resolve undefined
```

Note : I also tried the following

```
db.get(id.toString(), {include_docs: true}).then((result)
```

But same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to PouchDB [get() API](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#fetch_document) and its example response, the following modification is needed:

```
db.get(id).then((result) => {
    /* "result.row" is wrong */
    //character= result.row;
    /* Just do this: */
    character= result;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to resolve :

```
localCharacter(id: string){
let db = this._db;
let character: any;
console.log('Look for : ' + id + ' in local db');

return new Promise(resolve => {
  db.get(id).then((result) => {
    console.log('Character: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
    character= result.row;
    resolve(character); 
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Some errors : ' + error);
    character = false;
    resolve(character);
  });
})
  }
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can even simplify your code:

```
localCharacter(id: string) {
  return this._db.get(id).then(result => result.row).catch(err => false);
}
```

The `get` method returns a promise by itself, so there is no need to wrapping it into another promise.